# Dagger Hilt: How to pass an interface as a parameter to another class using dagger hilt in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I want to pass `Callbacks` which is an `interface` to this `RepositoryImpl` class like this:

```
class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
   private val callbacks: Callbacks
) : Repository { }
```

This is the `interface`:

```
interface Callbacks {

   fun onSomethingHappened()
}
```

And I want to use this `Callbacks` interface in a `fragment` like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment(), Callbacks {

    override fun onSomethingHappened() {}
}
```

**How should I write the Hilt `Module` to be able to provide the `Callbacks` interface to the `RepositoryImpl` class?**

This is what my current project looks like without the `Callbacks` interface:

`AppMain.kt`:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class AppMain : Application()
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){}
```

`MainFragment.kt`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: Repository
}
```

`RepositoryImpl.kt`

```
class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor() : Repository { }
```

`Repository.kt`

```
interface Repository { }
```

`HiltModule.kt`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindRepository(repositoryImpl: RepositoryImpl): Repository
}
```

Comment: You should not use callbacks but rather transform any method using a callbacks to suspend

Comment: @cutiko Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Take a look at this https://clmirror.storage.googleapis.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your solution, all I wanted was to use dependency injection using dagger hilt and somehow use an interface to listen to certain events and receive some results inside the fragment just like we do on a MVVM architectured app

Comment: My solution is: change your approach, you can solve the same problem in a better way, callbacks create messy code in comparison with linear code using asynchronous programming.